# only detect speech from user directly in front of Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to have kinect only pick up speech from a user who is directly in front of it.
I don't want noise or people talking on the right or left to be detected.
Or if the user moves to the right or left of the kinect.
Is this possible?

```
var audioSource = this.Kinect.AudioSource;
audioSource.BeamAngleMode = BeamAngleMode.Adaptive;
var kinectStream = audioSource.Start();
```

I have played around with ManualBeamAngle, but do not think that is what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.
cp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Source angle to find this, they are both 0 when in the middle. See [Audio Basics - WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131039.aspx), and change the code to this:

```
    double sourceAngle;

    ...

    private void AudioSourceBeamChanged(object sender, BeamAngleChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        beamRotation.Angle = -e.Angle;
        sourceAngle = e.Angle;
        beamAngleText.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.BeamAngle, e.Angle.ToString("0", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }

    private void AudioSourceBeamChanged(object sender, BeamAngleChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        beamRotation.Angle = -e.Angle;
        beamAngleText.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.BeamAngle, e.Angle.ToString("0", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }

    private void AudioReadingThread()
    {
        // Bottom portion of computed energy signal that will be discarded as noise.
        // Only portion of signal above noise floor will be displayed.
        const double EnergyNoiseFloor = 0.2;

        while (this.reading)
        {
            while (sourceAngle == 0) //this is the important part
            {
                int readCount = audioStream.Read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);

                // Calculate energy corresponding to captured audio in the dispatcher
                // (UI Thread) context, so that rendering code doesn't need to
                // perform additional synchronization.
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(
                    () =>
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < readCount; i += 2)
                        {
                            // compute the sum of squares of audio samples that will get accumulated
                            // into a single energy value.
                            short audioSample = BitConverter.ToInt16(audioBuffer, i);
                            this.accumulatedSquareSum += audioSample * audioSample;
                            ++this.accumulatedSampleCount;

                            if (this.accumulatedSampleCount < SamplesPerColumn)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            // Each energy value will represent the logarithm of the mean of the
                            // sum of squares of a group of audio samples.
                            double meanSquare = this.accumulatedSquareSum / SamplesPerColumn;
                            double amplitude = Math.Log(meanSquare) / Math.Log(int.MaxValue);

                            // Renormalize signal above noise floor to [0,1] range.
                            this.energy[this.energyIndex] = Math.Max(0, amplitude - EnergyNoiseFloor) / (1 - EnergyNoiseFloor);
                            this.energyIndex = (this.energyIndex + 1) % this.energy.Length;

                            this.accumulatedSquareSum = 0;
                            this.accumulatedSampleCount = 0;
                            ++this.newEnergyAvailable;
                        }
                    }));
            }
        }
```

The line `sourceAngle == 0)` does this for us. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this is great. So do you suggest I grab the value for beam angle and source angle and then check those values b4 i make any actions dependent on audio? example: void speechRecognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (beamAngle < -1 || beamAngle > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("beamAngle DENIED: " + beamAngle);
                return;
            }

Comment: I have found it is best to work with the SourceAngle to determine where the audio is coming from. probably obvious to others. thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sounds great! Sorry I didn't respond sooner, I was out :)